# Dumping fetchall() results to json

Tags: python, json, django

When i try to dump  fetchall() results (points coor) to json the result i obtain is

```
[[50, 15, 0], [55, 8, 9]]
```

witch is not a valid json format.

any ideas ?

```
def points_retriever(request):
    try:
        db = db_connection().db;
        db_manager= db_management(db);
        response = db_manager.retrieve_points()
        db.close() 

    except:
        response = 'Error'


    return render_to_response('points_retriever.html', {"points": simplejson.dumps(response)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid json. You can load it.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[[50, 15, 0], [55, 8, 9]]')
[[50, 15, 0], [55, 8, 9]]
```